# yocto defconfig not found

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, yocto

I'm attempting to create an image with yocto using a custom source (linux kernel 3.16).  When I attempt to run 'bitbake myCustomRecipe', I get a warning and error like the following:

```
WARNING: Unable to get checksum for myCustomRecipe SRC_URI entry defconfig: file could not be found
```

I have several other warnings/errors, but I believe that these follow naturally due to the above warning. My layer structure is like this:

```
meta-mytestLayer
|
+--conf/
|  |
|  +--layer.conf
|
+--recipes-kernel/
   |
   +--linux/
      |
      +--myCustomRecipe_3.16/
      |  |
      |  +--defconfig
      |
      +--myCustomRecipe_3.16.bb
```

As you can see, there is a defconfig file within the myCustomRecipe_3.16/ directory.  Why is this not being found? This file structure is very similar to the ones I have seen in several tutorials (like lab three of [this document](https://www.yoctoproject.org/sites/default/files/kernel-lab-1.4.pdf)).  My layer.config looks like this:

```
BBPATH .= ":${LAYERDIR}"

BBFILES += "${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bb \
    ${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bbappend"

BBFILE_COLLECTIONS += "myTestLayer"
BBFILE_PATTERN_myTestLayer = "^${LAYERDIR}/"
BBFILE_PRIORITY_myTestLayer = "6"
```

and my recipe looks like this:

```
inherit kernel
require recipes-kernel/linux/linux-yocto.inc

SRC_URI = "git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;protocol=git;nocheckout=1;name=machine"
SRC_URI += "file://defconfig"

LINUX_VERSION ?= "3.16"
LINUX_VERSION_EXTENSION ?= ""

SRCREV_machine="f14680f1692a9ec2a5b1b716a7a0c03dd391106f"

PR = "r1"
PV = "${LINUX_VERSION}+git${SRCPV}"

COMPATIBLE_MACHINE = "qemux86"
```

I'm a total yocto newbie and am looking at a number of labs/reference manuals/tutorials but haven't found anything related to this specific problem. I'm mostly working with the link I provided earlier and using [this section](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/kernel-dev/kernel-dev.html#working-with-your-own-sources) of the Yocto Project Linux Kernel Development Manual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have your `defconfig` file in a directory called `myCustomRecipe_3.16/`, while OpenEmbedded will look for the file in directories(1) named either of:

- `myCustomRecipe-3.16/`
- `myCustomRecipe/`
- `files/`

Note the '-' instead of '_'.

If you look at the `log.do_unpack` for your failed recipe, you'll see which directories has been searched for your defconfig.

(1) Well, that's only part of the story. Those three directories will be appended with directories for all your `OVERRIDES` as well.